# Hide blank column in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I need to hide an empty columns and fill the gap with next field in crystal report.

```
col1 col2 col3
val1 val2 val3
```

I used the suppress option with `if isnull({val2}) true else false` - If val2 is empty, it displays:

```
col1      col3
val1      val3
```

How can I hide the blank space in crystal report or in an action using MVC and C#?

```
col1 col3
val1 val3
```

Comment: You can't change columns width at run-time in crystal-reports

Comment: Whenever you write an `if ___ then true else false` statement, an angel cries. You can shorten your formula to just `isnull({val2})` and it'll have exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find an answer for that. You can write an action in your controller has the following code

```
ReportClass rpt;

rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["col2"].ObjectFormat.EnableSuppress = true;
rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["col3"].Left = rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["col2"].Left;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create three header formulas and three value formulas.
here is what the header 1 and value 1 formula might look like..

hdr1

```
if isnull(val1) then 
      if isnull(val2) then "Heading 3"
      else "Heading 2"
    else "Heading 1"
```

val1

```
if isnull(val1) then 
  if isnull(val2) then {val3}
  else {val2}
else {val1}
```